# Android ListView in Fragment using array

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a listview in my fragment, however I am getting error in my fragment class and adapter.

My fragment xml:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider2">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/MyAccountList"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

My list viewholder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- icon -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/option_icon"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:contentDescription="icon" />


    <!-- title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/option_icon"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/option_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyAccount_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {


private final Activity context;
private final String[] option_title;
private final Integer[] option_icon;


public MyAccount_Adapter(Activity context, String[] option_title, Integer[] option_icon) {
    //super(context, R.layout.myaccount_options_viewholder, option_title);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.option_title=option_title;
    this.option_icon=option_icon;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return option_title.length; //returns total of items in the array
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return option_title[position]; //returns item at the specified position
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.myaccount_options_viewholder, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.option_title);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.profile_icon);

    txtTitle.setText(option_title[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(option_icon[position]);
    return rowView;

};
}
```

And my fragment:

```
public class MyAccount extends Fragment {

ListView listView;
String[] optionTitle ={
        "booking record",
        "comments",
        "language",
};

Integer[] option_icon={

        R.drawable.booking_record_02,
        R.drawable.comment_record_02,
        R.drawable.language_02,
};


public MyAccount() {
}

public static MyAccount newInstance(String text){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_account, container, false);

    MyAccount_Adapter adapter=new MyAccount_Adapter(getActivity(), optionTitle, option_icon);
    listView=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.MyAccountList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

return rootView;

}
```

I am getting errors fragmentpageradapter cannot be applied in my adapter:

```
super(context, R.layout.myaccount_options_viewholder, option_title);
```

and another error MyAccount_Adapter cannot be applied and adapter cannot be applied in my fragment:

```
MyAccount_Adapter adapter=new MyAccount_Adapter(this, optionTitle, option_icon);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Is this caused by the context? I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Why fragmentpageradapter ? This is for ViewPager! https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You cannot set [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) to [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).

  Because [setAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)) in ListView needs [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) (Adapter which implements `ListAdapter`) as parameter.

  You can use [BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html).
- You cannot pass `this` as context for the adapter.

  Because `this` in fragment refers to that fragment, not activity.

  So, you need to pass `getActivity()`

Example Adapter:

```
public class MyAccount_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] option_title;
private final Integer[] option_icon;
public MyAccount_Adapter(Activity context, String[] option_title, Integer[] option_icon) {

    this.context=context;
    this.option_title=option_title;
    this.option_icon=option_icon;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return option_title.length; //returns total of items in the array
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return option_title[position]; //returns item at the specified position
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.myaccount_options_viewholder, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.option_title);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.profile_icon);

    txtTitle.setText(option_title[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(option_icon[position]);
    return rowView;

};
}
```

For optimizations refer this link: [Using a BaseAdapter with ListView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView)

**Update:**

You can get `listView` from `rootView` only, obviously as its existing there & cannot get from your activity using `getActivity()`

```
listView=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MyAccountList);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have made the following changes you said but now I am getting this error when I run the code : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference, can you teach me how to solve it?

Comment: @JerryKo Updated answer with sample adapter, if you have further doubt, update the code in your question with what you have implemented now

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have updated the code, but I still getting this error : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapte‌​r)' on a null object reference. After running the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

MyAccount_Adapter adapter=new MyAccount_Adapter(getActivity(),optionTitle, option_icon);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I have changed the code in from this to getActivity(), there are no more errors in my fragment class however in the adapter, I am still getting errors at super(context, R.layout.myaccount_options_viewholder, option_title); I think it might have something to do with my context can you please have a look?